# What’s the difference between Response.Write() and Response.Output.Write()?

Tags: asp.net, response.write

What’s the difference between `Response.Write()` and `Response.Output.Write()`?

Comment: See a more complete answer at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1794809/3834)

Answer (score 4):

There is effectively no difference, although `Response.Output.Write()` provides more overloads which can allow you to pass different parameters.  Scott Hansleman covers it [in depth](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETResponseWriteAndResponseOutputWriteKnowTheDifference.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

They both write to the output stream using a `TextWriter` (not directly to a Stream), however using `HttpContext.Response.Output.Write` offers more overloads (17 in Framework 2.0, including formatting options) than `HttpContext.Response.Write` (only 4 with no formatting options).

The `HttpResponse` type does not allow direct 'set' access to its output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really.

But. `Response.Write` takes the stream in the `Response.Output` property. You could set another Output stream, and in that way instead of writing back to the client, maybe write to a file or something crazy. So thats there relation.

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Output.Write()`: It is used to display any type of data like int, date, string etc. i.e. It displays the formatted output.

`Response.Write()`: To display only string type of data i.e. It's can't display formatted output().

To display formatted output from `Response.Write()` you can write:

```
Response.Write(String.Format("    ",___));
```