# What’s the difference between Response.Write() andResponse.Output.Write()?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between Response.Write() and Response.Output.Write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111417/whats-the-difference-between-response-write-and-response-output-write)

How is it different from response.write() and response.output.write()? Please explain.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[See this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/ViewForum.aspx?ForumId=10122):

The difference between `Response.Write()` and `Response.Output.Write()` in ASP.NET. The short answer is that the latter gives you `String.Format-style` output and the former doesn't. The long answer follows.

In ASP.NET the `Response` object is of type `HttpResponse` and when you say `Response.Write` you're really saying (basically) `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write` and calling one of the many overloaded `Write` methods of `HttpResponse`.

`Response.Write` then calls `.Write()` on it's internal `TextWriter` object:

```
public void Write(object obj){ this._writer.Write(obj);}
```

`HttpResponse` also has a Property called `Output` that is of type, yes, `TextWriter`, so:

```
public TextWriter get_Output(){ return this._writer; }
```

Which means you can do the `Response` whatever a `TextWriter` will let you. Now, TextWriters support a `Write()` method aka `String.Format`, so you can do this:

```
Response.Output.Write("Scott is {0} at {1:d}", "cool",DateTime.Now);
```

But internally, of course, this is happening:

```
public virtual void Write(string format, params object[] arg)
{ 
this.Write(string.Format(format, arg)); 
}
```

Comment: Stumbled on this from Google - the original content of the link (reproduced in this answer) is from an '04 post on Hanselman's blog - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETResponseWriteAndResponseOutputWriteKnowTheDifference.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Here Response.Write():to display only string and you can not display any other data type values like int,date,etc.Conversion(from one data type to another) is not allowed.
whereas Response .Output .Write(): you can display any type of data like int, date ,string etc.,by giving index values.

Here is example:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Write ("hi good morning!"+"is it right?");//only strings are allowed        
       Response.Write("Scott is {0} at {1:d}", "cool", DateTime.Now);//this will give error(conversion is not allowed)
       Response.Output.Write("\nhi goood morning!");//works fine
       Response.Output.Write("Jai is {0} on {1:d}", "cool", DateTime.Now);//here the current date will be converted into string and displayed
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

`Response.write()` is used to display the normal text and `Response.output.write()` is used to display the formated text.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, they are synonymous (`Response.Write` is simply a shorter way to express the act of  writing to the response output).

If you are curious, the implementation of `HttpResponse.Write` looks like this:

```
public void Write(string s)
{
    this._writer.Write(s);
}
```

And the implementation of `HttpResponse.Output` is this:

```
public TextWriter Output
{
    get
    {
        return this._writer;
    }
}
```

So as you can see, `Response.Write` and `Response.Output.Write` are truly synonymous expressions.

Comment: Thank u Mr. Andrew hare  for example

Comment: what about answers above ? they say response.write() and response.output.write() are different

Answer (score 1):

Response.write() don't give formatted output.
The latter one allows you to write formatted output.

Response.write - it writes the text stream
Response.output.write - it writes the HTTP Output Stream.

Comment: hi Tzury Bar Yochay what is the formatted output can u explain me thank u for response