# Why placeholder not work in Response.Write()?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Asp.net Web Application, I have a code like

```
string name = "manish";
int age = 24;

Response.Write("Name: {0}, Age: {1}", name, age);  // I have used placeholder
```

*Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'*

But it work fine in `Console.WriteLine()` method.

```
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Age: {1}", name, age);

Output: Name: manish, Age: 24
```

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation for the method you are calling? Just because its name is somewhat similar to `Console.WriteLine` is not a sufficient reason to expect that it works in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Response.Output.Write`this should work fine.

following code should work:

```
string name = "manish"; int age = 24;

Response.Output.Write("Name: {0}, Age: {1}", name, age);
```

Following is the reference that can be useful:

[What’s the difference between Response.Write() andResponse.Output.Write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794792/what-s-the-difference-between-response-write-andresponse-output-write)